# iOS 7 cancellation of interactive transition fails to release presented view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

When an interactive transition is cancelled, the presented view controller is never released (dealloc is never called).  When an interactive transition completes successfully, all is good, but when this transition is cancelled, it seems that the destination view controller is never released.  The result is memory loss, but not a memory leak (at least not detected by Instruments).  I could be doing something wrong, but I don't see what that is.  Since I have been unable to find any evidence that anybody else is having this problem, I assume it's me.

I have a very small sample project that demonstrates the issue (https://github.com/mparma-isi/InteractiveTransitionIssue.git).  A tap in the red square performs a transition to the second view controller.  A tap in the second controller dismisses that controller back to the first.  A pinch gesture inside the red square of the first view controller starts an interactive transition using UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition.  If you cancel the transition (negative velocity of the pinch) the presented view controller does not get released.  If you complete the transition, all works as expected.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Mike

Comment: I guess I'm a bit late to reply, but I'm facing this issue too. In fact, it exists in all examples I could find, so I guess it is safe to assume that this is a UIKit bug. Did you come up with a workaround, perhaps?

Comment: still true, any change?

Answer (score 0):

So I profiled this with Leaks instrument and found something interesting:

[image: Leaks instrument trace]

It seems that the memory leak comes from the highlighted line. There's no paired `-[UIWindow _remoteRotationViewController:]` call anywhere (whatever it is), so the window keeps our presented view controller alive.

Although pretty ugly, this workaround does the trick for me:

```
- (void)animationEnded:(BOOL)transitionCompleted {
    if (!transitionCompleted) {
        UIViewController *viewController = ...; // get the presented view controller

        UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"_removeRotationViewController:");
        if ([window respondsToSelector:selector]) {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
            [window performSelector:selector withObject:viewController];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
        }
    }
}
```

I'm going to file a Radar for this.